# How can I create a Category Index page that lists all categories?

Tags: categories

I have themed my category.php file so it now displays all posts that belong to the category that was clicked. The URL looks like [www.example.com/category/news/]. This is good and correct.

When I go to [www.example.com/category/] I am expecting to find a Category index page that lists all created categories but I receive a 404.

I have looked in the WP Codex and have not found anything that can help me create a Category index page. Is this possible? If so how do I go about starting? Please forgive me if this has already been answered as I may not be asking the right things.

**NOTE:** I know that I will be using the `wp_list_categories` function so that is not the question.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Create a custom template file in your theme e.g `"my-custom-template.php"`

2 - Create a page from the dashboard, and in the **page attributes box**(Right sidebar), select the custom template you've juste created as a **Model**.

3 - use `wp_list_categories` to get the list of your available categories...

hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had given thought to this but I wanted to check and see if there was a function or built in WP method I had not seen that I could use to achieve this result.

Comment: @Peter you welcome, I have never heard about a function doing that, instead there is some plugins that can do this... I think it's better you do it like I suggested above, because you will have a full control about the rendered html...